# What to do when a reviewer questions the writing style of your scientific research paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

This year, I submitted a research paper (case study) of a technology implementation to a peer reviewed journal. I waited approx. 2 months and the decision of the reviewer was to decline, because she considered it not to have the correct writing style for the journal.

What can be done, when is not the science and analysis being questioned, but rather the author's writing style ?

Comment: Did you consider changing the writing style? Maybe the reviewer has a point?

Comment: Was this submitted in English? I don't want to sound rude, but your English isn't quite native-like. So I would strongly encourage you to have a more fluent speaker (or editing service) take a look.

Comment: By style, did they refer to your actual writing style or rather the citation format etc.?

Comment: What does 'style' mean exactly? Some publishers require submitted papers to have a certain 'style' (single column, double spacing) before they send papers out for review.

Comment: @VitaminE But in that case one probably wouldn't hear back from "the reviewer". Of course, given that OP mentions "the reviewer's decision", maybe there's some confusion of reviewer and editor in the question.

Comment: You should really quote what they have said to you. As another said, it is even possible that style was there to paraphrase "the article is not suitable for this journal" . Unless unreadable at all, not formatting nor a bad English shall result in rejection. Or at least if so, I would expect some suggestions from the editors, like to involve a colleague etc.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'm Portuguese. I don't hide that fact from reviewers. And this should not be an eliminating factor for publishing science. Good Science will always be good regardless of English origins

Comment: @henning, they refer to the actual writing style. in regards to the case study presented with all mathematical & computer science explanations  no remarks

Comment: @VitaminE, the actual writing text style. Not the formatting of the document

Comment: You know, I can simply process the final research paper document, on a python script for a word polishing in a way it fits the editor most recent accepted papers writing styles. And is quite easy to do it, it really is. … of course there's the obvious quality reduction in word diversity throughout the text in said document.  But in the end will comply with such an odd requirement ....

Comment: @MiguelSilva-TechGuy Is this your first paper?  academic writing is quite different to essays.   You may use incorrect/bombastic words.  As a reviewer, I am wary of authors who do not know the correct vocabulary, especially technical terms.

Comment: @MiguelSilva-TechGuy "I can simply process the final research paper document, on a python script for a word polishing in a way it fits the editor most recent accepted papers writing styles" You have no idea what you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: @MiguelSilva-TechGuy You posted a question saying your English style was criticized ...

Comment: Does it say the english is bad or the writing is bad? Some people are just not very good at writing up things (until they learn).

Comment: not a bad English, no. It was a reference about writing style

Answer (score 9):

Likely you need to yield. I suspect that either the style is too informal or too pedantic. Readers of scientific paper have some expectations that you need to respect when possible.

The editor, of course, has the final say, and may agree or disagree with the reviewer. But the reviewer is probably familiar with the "expected" style of that journal. Ask the editor how much the style needs to be changed.

And, of course, examine some papers from that journal to get a sense of what the prefer to publish. Pioneers often get shot.

Comment: Also, consider that "not to have the writing style the journal" might be an euphemism. The reviewer might actually mean "unreadable due to language issues". There are professional services that can help.

Comment: @Roland, that is what i really don't tolerate on scientific reviewers: being vague on a work area where is expected to be exact and factual.  Nowadays Is also detrimental to both sides

Comment: @MiguelSilva-TechGuy This is a cultural issue. I am a German. I can assure you that I provide reviews that are brutally forthright. People from some cultures have issues with being direct. And even I sometimes hesitate to point out language issues because I understand the struggle. We routinely use a language service before submitting our manuscripts.

Comment: @Roland, i understand what you say. And Germans are known to be direct. The exact opposite of Portuguese. And in  that sense I'm more up north too.

Answer (score 8):

**Team up with an experienced researcher.** Many researchers are involved in the training of PhD students and, consequently, are used to working with people who lack experience in the writing of academic publications. For some, getting sub-optimal writing into shape might even come quite natural, and can lead to a win-win situation where both you and the researcher derive a benefit from a joint publication.

Your best bet are researchers with a background in the specific research area in which your paper is situated.

Comment: Grammatical revisions wouldn't merit authorship in my fields

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- True, I assume that the editing would go significantly beyond grammar revisions. In my field, the main roadblock for inexperienced writers is that they don't know to "shape the story" of a paper.

Comment: I guess that would still be borderline whether that's still worth authorship to me. Then again, it costs very little and if the field is better for getting this paper out there then it's probably fine

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Everyone Likes this answer, but as everyone knows, in academia, teaming up with an experienced researcher is not easy and it has a really high cost (in time). So your solution to me sounds much like demagogy / scientific politics at best.

Comment: @MiguelSilva-TechGuy Yes, if you want to have an outcome that meets the requirements, you will need to invest some time. My point is that you will probably waste even more time, on top of the time you've already wasted, if you keep doing this on your own, without input from someone more experienced.

Comment: That sounds at least borderline unethical, promising coauthorship for (even significant) rewriting.

Comment: @user151413 Provided that the coauthor indeed helps with "shaping the story" (which I assume is likely here), they can meet all four criteria for authorship laid out in the Vancouver protocol

Comment: I understand all those more political answers , towards the establishment. But I'm a scientist and I deal with real facts not great photos on LinkedIn. That said,  at the end it is fine by me, I just publish elsewhere. More so as Impact Factor dies away into the past, replaced with more metrics and a statement about a Autor's contribution.

Comment: @MiguelTomás-TheScientist You don't want to support the establishment? Great idea! Team up with a young but uprising researcher who doesn't have tenure yet and would actually benefit from the publication.

Comment: C'mon !!!! I'm way past that! What I'm inferring is something more urgent, for us here in Europe if we want to keep up in the lead ....

Comment: @MiguelTomás-TheScientist There are excellent young researchers in Europe that can write in the style expected by top journals.